# C - preprocessing mysql data whilst maintaining original copy for file write effectively

Tags: mysql, sql, c, linux, centos

** Edit -> I compiled this with:  gcc init.c `mysql_config --libs`

So, the program runs on server boot. I've already done a lot of data manipulation in Python and SQL, and the database this runs from is already generated.

The program basically runs a SELECT statement on a list of VPNS. Some of them are internal, some are not. The SELECT statement gets the already known internal nodes (lots of Python to work that one out) that are inside GB. On Lines 42-47 I have wrote some code to create a replica of the table I have built, and two rows of data. I've wrapped the SQL INSERTS in a helper function, so if you wanted to add more test data, just copy the lines and replace the text.

Anyways.. The problem is this:

As it stands, the program simply spits out the specified data into a text file. This is fine, but I also want to be able to preprocess the data before I write it to file, without affecting the file write.

I'm trying to isolate the third field (IP address) so that I can hand it off to various analytical tools. Any advice in which direction to go would be greatly appreciated :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
const int MAXLEN = 180;

// If any MySQL commands are unsuccessful, report error back and quit
void finish_with_error(MYSQL *con)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    mysql_close(con);
    exit(1);
}

// Helper function, sends a query to SQL
int send_query(MYSQL *con, char query[MAXLEN])
{
    if (mysql_query(con, query)) {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);

    FILE * fPtrOut;
    fPtrOut   = fopen("data.txt", "w");

    if (fPtrOut == NULL){
        printf("Unable to write to file.\nCheck permissions.\n" );
    }
    if (con == NULL){
        finish_with_error(con);
    }
    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", 
     "cTest", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL){
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    /* In the main program, this section does not exist... This is just to provide dummy data for testing purposes.*/
    send_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cTest");
    send_query(con, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 2dataFrame (id INT, domain VARCHAR(32), ip VARCHAR(15), flag VARCHAR(2), internal_node TINYINT, inRange INT(1), hops_taken INT(3))");
    send_query(con, "TRUNCATE 2dataFrame");
    send_query(con, "INSERT INTO 2dataFrame (id, domain, ip, flag, internal_node, inRange, hops_taken) VALUES ('590772', 'num01.example.com', '192.168.0.1', 'GB', '1', '1', '8')");
    send_query(con, "INSERT INTO 2dataFrame (id, domain, ip, flag, internal_node, inRange, hops_taken) VALUES ('946700', 'num02.example.com', '192.168.0.2', 'GB', '1', '1', '6')");

    /* This line refines the actual data set... Of course with the sample size, this line is basically redundant */
    send_query(con, "SELECT * FROM cTest.2dataFrame WHERE inRange = 1 AND flag = 'GB' AND hops_taken <= 9");

    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);
    if (result == NULL) {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    int i, x = 0;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    /* This function is the one I need help with
     * There's 7 fields in each line, and each 7 iterations, a newline is written to fPtrOut
     * At the minute, it writes them all to a text file. Ideally, I want a way to process it
     * before it writes to file- so that I can extrapolate the IP address from the 3rd field.
     * I am then going to use that in conjunction with code I've already written. I was debating
     * using strtok() but I'm trying to leave the original string unaltered, and be stringent on memory. 
     */
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) {
        for (i = 0; i < num_fields; i++){
            fprintf(fPtrOut, "%s\t", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
            x++;
            if (x == 7){
                fprintf(fPtrOut, "\n");
                x = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fPtrOut);
    mysql_free_result(result);
    mysql_close(con);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... Turns out the solution was staring me in the face the whole time. I never needed to actually isolate the third row, it was already done for me :)